# Service Unavailable 503 when trying to update to ASP.NET 4

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to update my web application from 3.5 to 4.0. I've changed to ASP.NET 4.0 Integrated application pool and removed from web.config all the unnecessary tags.

When I try now to access my site it says:

> ```
> Service Unavailable
> ```
>
> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

When I look in EventViewer for details I see:

```
Application pool 'ASP.NET 4.0 (Integrated)' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.
```

For one of the previous events I notice for instance:

```
A process serving application pool 'ASP.NET 4.0 (Integrated)' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '4040'. The process exit code was '0xfffffffe'.
```

I am not able to find other details for this issue which gets me desperate..Can you please give me any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-registering the .NET 4 Framework on the web application using aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Comment: If I try to run this from cmd, it says: 'aspnet_regiis.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Cannot this be done from IIS?

Comment: %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved...

The App. pool for .NET 4.0 was present but the .NET 4.0 itself was not installed.

After installing it, all works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this file http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30653 and choose "repairing". It helps me.